# CTE column caused an overflow - Order By only!

Tags: sql-server, cte

```
;WITH
cte_Date ( DateCode_FK ) AS (
    SELECT  DATEADD( DAY, 
                1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
                        ORDER BY so1.object_id ),
                GETDATE() )
    FROM    sys.objects so1
    CROSS APPLY sys.objects so2 )
SELECT  TOP 10 d.DateCode_FK
FROM    cte_Date d
ORDER BY d.DateCode_FK DESC;
```

Nothing an overly interesting query, but i'm receiving an error message if I run it with the `ORDER BY` clause:

> Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

However, without the `ORDER BY` clause, it runs just fine.  In addition, if I run the query on other catalogs contained in the same instance on the same server, the query runs fine with or without the `ORDER BY` clause.

I've taken a look at the configuration options and compatibility levels between the affected catalog and a catalog on which the query runs as expected, but have not found anything that might warrant the difference.  Has anybody else run into a similar issue?  I can work around it for now, but would ideally need to be able to fix the problem, whatever it is.

Potential hint - if you have a relatively large number of objects in a catalog ( > 5000 ), you -may- be able to reproduce the error... This is occurring on my largest catalog and it appears that if I include a TOP in the CTE, the ORDER BY issue goes away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server does not guarantee the timing or number of evaluations for scalar expressions. This means that a query that *might* throw an error *depending on the order of operations* in an execution plan might (or might not) do so at runtime.

The script uses `CROSS APPLY` where `CROSS JOIN` was probably intended, but the point is that the potential number of rows over which the `ROW_NUMBER` is calculated depends on the size of the `sys.objects` cross product.

For a database with sufficient objects, an overflow for the `DATEADD` result is an expected risk. For example, this is reproducible using the *AdventureWorks* sample database, which has 637 entries in `sys.objects`. The size of the cross product is 637 * 637 = 405,769; the following throws an overflow error:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - 405769, GETDATE());
```

One might argue that there is no need to materialize the result of an expression [for rows that are not returned](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) (and therefore not throw an error), but that is not the ways things work today.

Consider:

- The *highest* `ROW_NUMBER` will give the *lowest* value for `DateCode_FK` in the `DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ROW_NUMBER()...` expression
- The presentation `ORDER BY` is `DateCode_FK DESC`
- Only the first 10 rows in presentation order are required

If the optimizer contained logic to reason that *lower* row numbers lead to *higher* `DateCode_FK` values, an explicit Sort would not be needed. Only ten rows would need to flow through the execution plan. The ten lowest row numbers are guaranteed to produce the ten highest `DateCode_FK` values.

Regardless, even where a Sort is present, the argument is that SQL Server should not throw an error because none of the ten rows actually returned are associated with an overflow error. As I said above, *"that is not the ways things work today"*.

---

An alternative formulation that avoids the error (though it is still not *guaranteed* to do so - see my opening remark), makes the row numbering deterministic, and uses `CROSS JOIN`:

```
WITH cte_Date (DateCode_FK) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (10)
        DATEADD
        (
            DAY, 
            1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
                ORDER BY 
                    so1.[object_id],
                    so2.[object_id]),
            GETDATE()
        )
    FROM sys.objects AS so1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects AS so2
    ORDER BY
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY 
                so1.[object_id],
                so2.[object_id]) ASC
)
SELECT TOP (10) -- Redundant TOP
    d.DateCode_FK
FROM cte_Date AS d
ORDER BY 
    d.DateCode_FK DESC;
```

[Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1WxakzBl)

[image: Plan]

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

Holiday hangover I guess.

The `ORDER BY` in the external part of the query sometimes forces the building of the full list in order to correctly order it.  With 5k+ rows returned from `sys.objects`, the `DATETIME` data type overflows while trying to build dates over 25MM days old.